# Change character in Tedit Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Sorry for my bad english. How to block a character in TEdit if I have text 'Kamu' in first TEdit and 'Dia' in 2nd TEdit where character is 'a' and change them to 'i' in 3rd TEdit?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`StringReplace`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TReplaceFlags).

```
NewValue := StringReplace(OldValue, 'a', 'i', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

You may want to omit `rfIgnoreCase` depending on your needs. You can read from and write to the content of the `TEdit` control by using its `Text` property. For instance:

```
Edit1.Text := StringReplace(Edit1.Text, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip, David. I'll try to use StringReplace :)