# put cursor in wrong Tedit text Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have 2 Tedit. First has string 'amanda' and second has string 'amonda'. The second is wrong string because there is an 'o' of 'amanda'. If both not match, then how to put cursor in front of 'o' from Tedit 2? Sorry for my bad english

Comment: How did you get on here by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961459/change-character-in-tedit-delphi

Comment: Is your question targeting finding the difference between the two strings, or positioning the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SelStart` and `SelLength` properties. For instance, to place the caret at index `I` you would do this:

```
Edit1.SelStart := I;
Edit1.SelLength := 0;
```

Note that `I` is zero-based. So a value of 0 places the caret before the first character, a value of 1 places it before the second character, and so on.

I'm presuming that you already know how to identify the index of the character which you wish to highlight.

Note finally that you used the term *cursor* incorrectly. That's the thing that you move around the screen with your mouse. You mean the *caret*, the flashing vertical bar that indicates the text insertion point in an edit control.

Comment: Oh, sorry, Im still learning english. Thank you for correcting my question and for quick answer :)